# Docker private registry catalog items not found on server

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a private insecure registry on an Ubuntu Server 18.04 (using docker-compose), whose IP is let's say 192.168.168.168; when on a Windows client I browse from Chrome to

http://192.168.168.168:5000/v2/_catalog

I get

```
{"repositories":["hello-world2","mywebservice"]}
```

which is ok, since I pushed them to the private registry.
However, if I run

```
docker image list
```

on the server, only "hello-world2" is shown. There's no "mywebservice" entry.
How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, a registry is a separate entity which has no direct relationship with the Docker client possibly installed on the same server where the registry is.

In other words, if I push an image from a Docker client on machine A to the registry on machine B, any Docker client on machine B won't get that image unless it explicitly pulls that image from the registry, even if the registry is on the same machine B.

In my case I didn't pull the "mywebservice" image from the registry to the client, both on machine B.